# Read hidden extension of file from link

Tags: php

I need to read pdf extension file from some links which I crawled from a web. The links is saved in `$link` variable.
but sometimes, the extension doesn't written in the link, for example : `http://tstc.bz/docs/490` besides 490 is a pdf file, the extension will exist when I click it. How to read that hidden extension ? thank you
I've tried using `PATHINFO`

```
if (strtolower(pathinfo($link,PATHINFO_EXTENSION)) === 'pdf'){
```

Comment: Follow the redirects and check the mime type.

Answer (score 2):

Use `mime_content_type`, documentation [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mime-content-type.php), to fetch the type of the file you're trying to load.

If you are caching the content of the links, this is a good option, as you need to have the file locally. Otherwise, do like baba is suggesting, use `get_headers` with the link (documentation [here](https://www.php.net/get_headers)), passing a non-zero value as the second parameter to have the `keys` in your result array. Then, it's simply a matter of reading `[Content-Type]` from your resulting array

Comment: yes it works ... but not on a link ... can you give it a try that is why i used [mime_content_type("http://google.com");](http://codepad.viper-7.com/BvNUVL) as example ...

Answer (score 1):

You can use `get_headers`

```
$link = "http://tstc.bz/docs/490";
if (getPdf($link)) {
    // yes its a PDF File
}
```

Function Used

```
function getPdf($link) {
    $ext = strtolower(pathinfo($link, PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
    if (empty($ext)) {
        $type = array_change_key_case(get_headers($link, true), CASE_LOWER);
        if (is_array($type['content-type']))
            return false;
        if (strtolower($type['content-type']) === "application/pdf") {
            return true;
        }
    }
    if ($ext === 'pdf') {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: fyi, I crawled a page from google scholar, for example this page = http://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&q=text+summarization&btnG=&as_sdt=1%2C5&as_sdtp= I should get 9 links that contain PDF files, and I've tried using your code, it still grabs 7 links only.

Comment: I usually test my scripts .. http://codepad.viper-7.com/XAjgVR ... it returns `9` links